# Why the view of some photos read by cv2.imread and plt.imread are different?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, imread

I have some photos taken by UAV, and I find that the view of some photos read by cv2.imread and plt.imread are different, one of them is upside down (180° rotation), but most photos are the same.

Why?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike matplotlib (PIL), opencv takes EXIF information into account by default, see [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#imread):

> If EXIF information is embedded in the image file, the EXIF
> orientation will be taken into account and thus the image will be
> rotated accordingly except if the flags IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION or
> IMREAD_UNCHANGED are passed.

(to achieve the same with PIL, use [exif_transpose](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.exif_transpose))

Comment: oh, I accepted. I didn't know the function before.